# My blog only retrieves one post

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm creating a blog in C# MVC, but I'm having a problem with the blog posts. From a list of posts, only one post is retrieved, and it's the last one. I wanna retrieve all blog posts with their associated images...

BLOG MODELS

```
 public class Blog
{
    [Key]
    public int BlogID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Post> Posts { get; set; }

}
public class Post
{
    [Key]
    public int PostID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public int BlogID { get; set; }
    public bool hasImages { get; set; }
    public virtual Blog Blog { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ImageFile> ImageFiles { get; set; }
}
public class ImageFile
{
    [Key]
    public int ImageID { get; set; }
    public string ImageName { get; set; }
    public string ImageType { get; set; }
    public byte[] ImageBytes { get; set; }
    public int PostID { get; set; }
    public virtual Post Post { get; set; }
}
```

METHOD TO RETRIEVE POSTS + IMAGES

```
 public Tuple<IEnumerable<Post>, IEnumerable<ImageFile>> getAllBlogData()
        {
            var AllPosts = _entities.Posts.ToList();

            Tuple<IEnumerable<Post>, IEnumerable<ImageFile>> model = null;

            foreach (var post in AllPosts)
            {
                var posts = AllPosts.Where(e => e.PostID == post.PostID);
                if (posts != null)
                {
                    //checks if a blog post has images
                    if (post.hasImages)
                    {
                        var images = _entities.ImageFiles.Where(e => e.PostID == post.PostID);
                        model = new Tuple<IEnumerable<Post>, IEnumerable<ImageFile>>(posts, images);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        model = new Tuple<IEnumerable<Post>, IEnumerable<ImageFile>>(posts, null);
                    }
                }
            }
            return model;
        }
```

CONTROLLER

```
public ActionResult Posts()
  {
     return View(_blogrepository.getAllBlogData());
  }
```

VIEW

```
@model Tuple<IEnumerable<Winter.Domain.Entities.Post>, IEnumerable<Winter.Domain.Entities.ImageFile>>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Posts";
}

<hgroup>
    <h3>BLOG</h3>
</hgroup>



@foreach (var post in Model.Item1)
{
    <p class="container images">

        @if (Model.Item2 != null)
        {
            foreach (var image in Model.Item2)
            {
                <span>
                    <img src="data:image/png;base64,@Convert.ToBase64String(image.ImageBytes)" />
                </span>
            }
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
        }


        <hgroup>
            <h2>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => post.Title)</h2>
        </hgroup>

        <span>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => post.Content)
        </span>
    </p>
}

<hr />
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please note that the model-view-controller tag is for questions about the pattern. There is a specific tag for the ASP.NET-MVC implementation.

Comment: `Tuple<IEnumerable<Post>, IEnumerable<ImageFile>> getAllBlogData()` Firstly it should be GetAllBlogData() and secondly, this is a terrible way of getting the data that you need. Either have two methods that return posts and image files separately, or add `ImageFile` onto the `Post` class.

Comment: It's taken a long enough time, and I noticed @user9993 commented as I was writing, but I've posted an answer below to the same effect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below, I give you 2 ways of making your code work.

The first being the "correct" way to implement what you're trying to do and the second being a fix of the current code you're using.

Get a beverage, and have a good read. *note: this is all off the top of my head (so please forgive in advance - just comment anything that needs correcting)*

## 1) The "correct" way to do it:

It looks like you're using Entity Framework. (If not, then *why not*?)

That said, I would look into [Entity Framework Relationships & Navigation Properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/data/jj713564.aspx).

This is *exactly* what Database Relationships are for. Your code is currently making heavy work of what is an in-built feature, and you're using `Tuple`s unnecessarily. EF is there to allow you to use *real* objects you've already created.

Here's a short(ish) way you should update your structure (this example is using EF Code-First - I find it way easier to create the DB from already-made classes that I use around the program):

### Classes

```
public class Post
{
    public int Id { get;set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    // Other properties etc.

    public virtual ICollection<ImageFile> Images { get; set; }
}

public class ImageFile
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public byte[] ImageBytes { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(Post))]
    public int PostId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(PostId))]
    public Post Post { get; set; }
}
```

This gives you a one-to-many relationship of "one post" has "many image files". The `virtual` property of `Images` in the `Post` class means it is a "navigation property" - this means that EF can figure out the relationship between the `ImageFile` that have the matching `PostID` to that post. This is down to FluentAPI's convention (TL;DR)

See how [Code First Relationships](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/data/hh134698.aspx) work in Entity Framework for more information.

### Controller

Your controller can then return a `List<Post>` from your context.

```
public ActionResult Posts()
{
    var posts = _yourDbContext.Posts.Include(x => x.Images).ToList();

    return View(posts);
}
```

**Note:** You will need to include `using System.Data.Entity` at the top of your file's using statements, in order to use the `Include()` method with a lambda expression.

**Further note:** If you don't "flatten" the results to a `List<>`, then you *might not* (off the top of my head) need to use the `Include()` method - TL;DR: when the page is rendered, it will still have the context in scope, and will be able access the navigation properties using the query (`IQueryable<>`) it still uses (lazy loading). `Include()` simply uses eager loading to pull the images out and place them in the `List<>`.

### View

Then, in your view you can simply use the `@model` as an `IEnumerable<Post>`, iterating over the List/IEnumerable you passed in; referencing the `Images` property that way.

Like so:

```
@model IEnumerable<Your.Namespace.Post>

// Other fluff - page title etc.

@foreach (var post in Model)
{
    foreach (var image in post.Images)
    {
        // Display each image - @image.ImageBytes
    }

    <h1>@post.Title</h1>
    // Other @post.Property printing, here
}
```

Using this way will enable you to (use a lot less code), and use your classes for what they would usually be designed for in OOP.

---

I have also included a "dirty" answer - using the current method you're using, below:

---

## 2) The "dirty" fix of your code:

Similar to @Jauch's answer, but a little more condensed for both the code, and your view:

Your `getAllBlogPosts()` method is simply returning the last post in the iteration, every time - you're overwriting `model` each time.

You could simply return a list of blog posts like this:

```
private List<Tuple<Post, IEnumerable<ImageFile>>> GetAllBlogPosts()
{
    var allPosts =
        _entities.Posts.Select(
           post =>
                new Tuple<Post, IEnumerable<ImageFile>>(
                    post,
                    _entities.ImageFiles.Where(x => x.PostID == post.PostID)));

    return allPosts.ToList();
}
```

Then, in your view you can simply iterate the `.Item2` property (the images), without having to do a `null` check beforehand.

This is because, even if there are no results, the `IEnumerable<ImageFile>` will result as simply an empty collection.

In the view, your model will be an `IEnumerable<Tuple<Post, IEnumerable<ImageFile>>>` *( where`FQNS` is the fully qualified namespace of your classes)*:

```
 @model IEnumerable<Tuple<FQNS.Post, IEnumerable<FQNS.ImageFile>>>
```

Your view can then iterate over each `Tuple` in the `Model` - let's say `item`.

Then inside the `item`, you can reference `Value1` (being the `Post`) and `Value2` (being the `Post`'s images).

Like so:

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <p class="container images">
        foreach (var image in item.Item2)
        {
            <span>
                <img src="data:image/png;base64,@Convert.ToBase64String(image.ImageBytes)" />
            </span>
        }
        <div class="clearfix"></div>

        <hgroup>
            <h2>@Html.DisplayFor(x => item.Value1.Title)</h2>
        </hgroup>

        <span>
            @Html.DisplayFor(x => item.Value1.Content)
        </span>
    </p>
}
```

---

I hope that this helps you along the way with your project, whichever method you take.

I would heavily advise to research into EF's relational capabilities and using navigation properties in order to make your code much cleaner (and your life much easier).

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: The first way worked perfectly. And there's very little code involved, I love it. I'm still gonna try the second one though just to verify... Thank you so so much :)

Comment: Glad to be of help! Hope you get the second one to work, also - although, I digress the first option is most definitely the "proper" way of doing it. Don't forget to upvote, too, if the answer is usfeul :)

Answer (score 1):

I would say that the problem is in this part of the code:

```
public Tuple<IEnumerable<Post>, IEnumerable<ImageFile>> getAllBlogData()
{
    var AllPosts = _entities.Posts.ToList();

    Tuple<IEnumerable<Post>, IEnumerable<ImageFile>> model = null;

    foreach (var post in AllPosts)
    {
        var posts = AllPosts.Where(e => e.PostID == post.PostID);
        if (posts != null)
        {
            //checks if a blog post has images
            if (post.hasImages)
            {
                var images = _entities.ImageFiles.Where(e => e.PostID == post.PostID);
                model = new Tuple<IEnumerable<Post>, IEnumerable<ImageFile>>(posts, images);
            }
            else
            {
                model = new Tuple<IEnumerable<Post>, IEnumerable<ImageFile>>(posts, null);
            }
        }
    }
    return model;
}
```

First, you load all posts:

```
var AllPosts = _entities.Posts.ToList();
```

Then you iterate on each post on AllPosts, and look for all posts that have the same ID than this one:

```
foreach (var post in AllPosts)
{
    var posts = AllPosts.Where(e => e.PostID == post.PostID);
```

Assuming that PostID is a "unique" KEY (like you showed in the code), you will find just the post itself.

Than you create the "model". And do this for each post. At the end, "model" will contain only the last post from the first foreach.

I think you need to return a "list" of posts (and associated images), so, I would try to change the code in this way:

```
public List<Tuple<Post, IEnumerable<ImageFile>>> getAllBlogData()
{
    var list = new List<Tuple<Post, IEnumerable<ImageFile>>();
    Tuple<Post, IEnumerable<ImageFile>> tuple = null;
    var AllPosts = _entities.Posts.ToList();
    foreach (var post in AllPosts)
    {
        //checks if a blog post has images
        if (post.hasImages)
        {
            var images = _entities.ImageFiles.Where(e => e.PostID == post.PostID);
            tuple = new Tuple<Post, IEnumerable<ImageFile>>(post, images);
        }
        else
        {
            tuple = new Tuple<Post, IEnumerable<ImageFile>>(post, null);
        }

        list.Add(tuple);
    }

    return list;
}
```

And, of course, adapt you file to deal with the list instead of the "model".

The code above should return all the posts in your blog, through a list that has tuples where on data is the POST, and the other is the list of images associated with that post.

Comment: You're missing a closing `>` from the signature of the `getAllBlogData()` method. Should be: `List<Tuple<Post, IEnumerable<ImageFile>>>` :)

Comment: Thanks. Corrected :)